# existing limit and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb R$ continuous function that is differentiable in every $x \in (a, b)$ except $x_0$. Show that if there exists a finite limit

$L =  \lim_{x \to x_0} f´(x)$

then $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ and $f´(x_0) = L$

I think I have a kind of a hunch here, maybe by using MVT? But I'm not sure how to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

From the mean value theorem, for $a<x_0<x<b$, there exists a number $\bar x\in (x_0,x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(\bar x)$.

Take the limit as $x\to x_0$ from the right.  The limit is $L$.  Now, show that the limit from the left exists.